# ¿Por qué se oculta parte del contenido cuando lo pongo en responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

No sé porque se oculta parte del contenido, la parte superior del div cuando lo pongo en pantallas pequeñas, y no se muestra la foto ni el nav, se ocultan, el scroll no se inicia desde la parte superior sino desde cierta posicion.

```css
.tarjeta {
  max-width: 700px;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="m-0 vh-100 row justify-content-center align-items-center text-center  ">
        <div
            class="container  tarjeta position-absolute col-sm-8  shadow-lg   bg-info  bg-opacity-75 rounded-4 border border-4 border-warning ">
            <ul class="mt-2    nav justify-content-center bg-info shadow bg-gradientmt-2 rounded-4 border border-2  border-dark ">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link active link-warning text-white" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled link-warning text-white" href="#">Skills</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled link-warning text-white" href="#">Portafolio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled link-warning text-white">Redes</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled link-warning text-white ">Contacto</a>
                </li>
            </ul> 

            <div class="row align-items-center mt-5 ">
                <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-3 pb-3   ">
                    <img class="text-center img-fluid  rounded-4 border border-4  border-success shadow-lg "
                        src="assets/img/perfil.JPG" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6  pb-3 ">
                    <img class="text-center img-fluid  " id="logo" src="assets/img/pc-removebg-preview.png" alt="logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12  col-md-3  pb-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Portafolio</button>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="row mt-4">
                <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                    <p>Gran capacidad de toma de decisiones y solvento de problemas de forma creativa con el fin de
                        obtener los objetivos deseados, adaptandome a los posibles escenarios que define nuestra
                        profesión.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-4 mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Redes Sociales</button>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

no aparece el scroll completo, quiero decir para que se vea la parte superior del div tarjeta,
estoy usando css html y bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

vale, es por la `position-absolute`

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta.